# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: unknown. After updating android studio to ver 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio 2.2.3 ,I am getting

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: unknown.
```

Please Help guys

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your "Gradle Console" on the bottom right side of your Android Studio

Comment: did you clear gradle cache of android studio?

Comment: I have done everything..but still getting error

Comment: clean-rebuild and do gradle

Comment: Done that...I have uninstalled and then reinstalled the latest version of android studio.Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

File->Setting->Build, Deployment & Execution->Build Tools->Gradle->Gradle Vm Option

Now put this value -Xmx256m in the box, and hit the Apply button.